# How can I load a module at runtime?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, load

I just compiled the `qcserial` module which is a driver module for a Gobi USB modem. Now I have a couple of questions.

1. Now I have two files: `drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.ko` and `drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.o` which one is the correct driver?
2. Also, as I understand, it will need to go into `/lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/` but how do I know which sub directories from there onwards?
3. Should I just be able to copy the files over and then load with `modprobe qcserial`?

What I have tried so far:

```
root@ariag25:~# mkdir /lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/usb/serial
root@ariag25:~# cp drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.ko /lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/
root@ariag25:~# ls -l /lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/usb/serial
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17921 Jan  1 18:30 qcserial.ko
root@ariag25:~# modprobe qcserial
FATAL: Module qcserial not found.
root@ariag25:~#
```

What am I missing? Do I also need to copy the `.o` file?

From where I compiled it, I have:

```
ls -l drivers/usb/serial/qc*
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg  3776 Oct 18 18:24 drivers/usb/serial/qcaux.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg  3212 Dec 28 10:14 drivers/usb/serial/qcaux.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg 12577 Oct 18 18:24 drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg 17921 Dec 28 10:44 drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg  7743 Dec 28 10:44 drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.mod.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg 11688 Dec 28 10:44 drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.mod.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 reg reg  6912 Dec 28 10:44 drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.o
```

**edit for Answer 1**

Ok, I copied my `linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` into the target's `/tmp/`. I then executed `tar -C / -tvf linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` to extract it onto `/` but after this, I still would get

```
# modprobe qcserial
FATAL: Module qcserial not found.
```

I then wondered if the driver gat even copied:

```
# tar -C / -tvf linux-3.11.6-arm.tar | grep qcserial
-rw-r--r-- root/root     17921 2013-12-28 13:22 lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/qcserial.ko
```

so that looks fine, but if I want to `ls` it, `# ls /lib/modules/3.11.6/kernel/drivers/usb/` there's no `serial` directory within `usb/` - why not? What happened?

Comment: Why don't you want to compile the module "statically" i.e. '*' instead of 'M'?

Comment: Because at this point, I can not reload the complete kernel structure & rootfs. However, it's a fair question :)

Comment: What embedded distro are you using?

Comment: @yegorich embedded debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a kernel package (`make tar-pkg`). Then copy it to your ARM system, for example to `/tmp` and extract to `/`. You'll get all driver modules installed into correct folders including proper `modules.dep` and other files needed to automatically resolve module dependencies.

`modprobe qcserial` should be working then.

Comment: I instead did a `make tar-pkg -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-` to get it compiled for the correct `arch`, I now have a `linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` seemingly including all the modules, not only qcserial. I also got a message like "** ** **  WARNING  ** ** ** Your architecture did not define any architecture-dependent files
to be placed into the tarball. Please add those to /home/reg/semios/linux-3.11.6/scripts/package/buildtar ..." - which I don't understand... what "architecture-dependent files" does that refer to?

Comment: @cerr don't pay attention to this warning. As long as you get `linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` everything is O.K. Btw you can remove `/boot` folder from the archive. This archive has all drivers, that you have compiled as modules. I've also used Embedded Debian and used this method to install driver modules.

Comment: FYI: If you don't necessarily need to use Debian, you could use [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It would install modules direct to your rootfs archive during the building stage.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use debian for this one, it 'just' came with it sio i decieded to go ahead with it. I've used buildroot on other platforms before but would need to figure out some basics again before i can get started...

Comment: If you have used `tar -C / -tvf linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` for extraction, than you have just listed the files. You should use `tar -C / -xvf linux-3.11.6-arm.tar` to extract files, i.e. `-x` option.

Answer (score 2):

There are two utilities to load modules: `insmod` and `modprobe`. `insmod` is a low-level utility: it loads a module file, given by its full path. `modprobe` is a high-level utility: you pass it a module name, and it looks up that module name in the module database, loads any necessary dependencies then loads the module itself. If the module isn't recorded in the module database, `modprobe` fails.

In addition to copying the module file, you need to [update the module database](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod). Run `depmod -a` to regenerate the whole database`.

It doesn't matter where you put the module file as long as it's somewhere under `/lib/modules/3.11.6` (where `3.11.6` is your kernel version as returned by `uname -r`). Normally the `kernel` subdirectory is reserved for modules that came with the kernel itself, you should put yours in another subdirectory.